# Script for converting html markup to valid XML

Tags: .net, xml, xhtml, html-parsing, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG editor that builds HTML content.  The tags are not always built as valid xml, and I need it to be valid xml.  Does anyone have such a script?  How would I do this?

Comment: Any chance you can fix the editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you are using on the server but you might want to look into the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you are using .NET

Comment: I found that Html Agility Pack has got some bugs. In some cases in produces invalid XML.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth having a look at this .NET version of HTML Tidy: [Tidy.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools such as John Cowan's TagSoup that do a good job of converting HTML to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft released a code sample : [SgmlReader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader). It allow you to read (among other formats) tidy html.

I wrote a small utility method that convert an Html string to an xml string:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a string from potential dirty HTML to valid XML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The string to convert</param>
/// <returns>A valid XML fragment that contains the cleaned HTML</returns>
/// <remarks>This methods only format the html to an xml compatible parser.
/// The method does not clean dangerous tags from the source string</remarks>
public static string HtmlToXHtml(string input)
{
    using (var sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        var hr = new SgmlReader(sr);
                    hr.InputStream = sr;
                    hr.DocType = "HTML";
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        var hw = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(output));

        hr.Read();
        while (!hr.EOF)
        {
            hw.WriteNode(hr, true);
        }


        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can "simply" update the user input after the postback.
In more complex scenarios (having to switch between the wysiwyg and the Html source mode), you may require a bit of Ajax to convert the html string to an xhtml behind the curtain, before showing the html source in the textarea.